# Fullcalendar: How to change the default end date

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar, momentjs

How do I change the default `endDate` of an event? My set up is - When I click (`select`) on a day, a modal should pop up with the fields I need it to display. However, when it comes to dates, fullcalendar sets the default date to + 1 day as seen below.

**modal section displaying time**

[image]

As you see when I click on the 14th, the 15th is set as the endDate. Why is that and how can I change it? I need default settings that allow me to enter 'project' details for one day without touching/adjusting end date (should match the start date in cases where the project is just a day long).

**PS:** Everything works. I just find it cumbersome to always adjust end date for a day long project. I have tried out several solutions on forums without success.

**controller.js** [angularjs]

```
           select: function(start, end){
                $scope.showSelected = false;
                var fromDate = moment(start).format('DD/MM/YYYY LT');
                var endDate  = moment(end).format('DD/MM/YYYY LT');

                $scope.Project = { 
                    ProjectID : 0,
                    Client: '',
                    Title : '',
                    Description: '',
                    Employees: '',
                    StartAt : fromDate,
                    EndAt : endDate,
                    IsFullDay : false
                }
                $scope.ShowModal()

            },
```

Comment: Is your calendar in month view? If so I think fullcalendar will default to end date of +1 day if no end date is specified and or allDay for the event is not set to false. See **[allDayDefault](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/allDayDefault/)**, **[defaultAllDayEventDuration](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/defaultAllDayEventDuration/)**, and **[defaultTimedEventDuration](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/defaultTimedEventDuration/)**

Comment: @smcd yes my calendar is in month view. `allDay` is set to `isFullDay` which is `false`.